# How to add attributes to go.js nodes and redirection

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, gojs

I'm using go.js and I added a ContextMenu to my diagram. One of the buttons is a "visit" button, which should redirect user to a certain URL. My problem is that those URLs are generated using IDs. I wanted to know if it's possible to set some attributes to a node, and use them in my contextMenu.

I'm using a `go.panel` for creating my nodes, and some `go.TextBlock` in them. All the data used to create the nodes are from a JSON array, exactly like in [this example](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/orgChartStatic.html)

Here is my contextMenu :

```
$(go.Adornment, "Vertical",
    $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Visit",
            { click: function(e, obj) { VisitGroup(obj); } }))

);
```

I dont know how to set attributes to nodes, and how to access any information related to the node. Thanks !

Comment: please provide all codes to help better

Comment: I found a solution using `ob.part.data` to access the json values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, setting storing the info in the node data and using `obj.part.data` is the correct way to do this.

That works because `Adornment.data` will be the same as `Adornment.adornedPart.data` - all Adornments are bound to the same data as the adorned Part.